# Use a function inside an module.exports

Tags: node.js, coffeescript

I'm trying to build a module which encloses the following function inside:

```
    request urlString, (error, response, body) ->
        return JSON.parse(body) if !error && response.statusCode == 200
```

It's all enclosed by the module.exports. The function executes, but I'm not able to return the body from the callback in request.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You likely need to include more code than you have here, please be more explicit

Comment: @elbou: You can't `return` from inside a callback. Your second parameter to `request` is a *callback*, a function which you send to request, and request _calls back_ for you, when it has the data you want. You can't return from there, because the code inside the callback's body is in another scope (executed much later than the code immediately following your request call). You need to also use a callback as a parameter to the calling function, and invoke that with your result.

Answer (score 0):

i think what you want is parseJSON func. even though i may use this code directly:

```
#file requestJSON.js


requestJSON = (urlString, callback)->
    request urlString, (error, response, body) ->
        if !error && response.statusCode == 200
            bodyJSON = JSON.parse body
        calllback error,bodyJSON
        return

module.exports=requestJSON


#file requestJSON.usage.js

requestJSON = require "./requestJSON"
requestJSON "json API", (error,jsonData)->
    console.log jsonData
    return
```